# orden serie geom_col

Tags: ggplot, graph

quiero cambiar el orden en que se presentan las series en un grafico.
Desde abajo hacia arriba primero aparece 'Octubre 2022' y necesito sea 'Octubre 2023'.
No encuentro como hacerlo. Gracias.

Escribí el siguiente código:

```
g_5= ggplot(data=SectPriv_graf , aes(x=reorder(letra, desc(letra)), y=IMS_12meses, fill=periodo, labels=letra))+
```

geom_col (width=0.8, position= position_dodge2(), alpha=0.4) +
coord_flip()

[image: Variacion 12 meses por Seccion]